# Iterating trough global environment with loop

Tags: r, iteration

I would like to iterate trough the Global Environment (only the dataframes) and adding to every dataframe in the .GlobalEnv a column. Furthermore, the entry to this column is dependend to a list `index`.

As a result I want to get for `dataframe1` a new column with the entry `index[1]`. For `dataframe2` I want a column with entry `index[2]` and so on.
Also, the changes should be made directly to the objects in the .GlobalEnv, since the dataframes contain `NA` and therefore I would not be able to export them with `list2env(dfs, .GlobalEnv)`.

My try:

```
index = c(a, b, c, d)
dfs = lapply(filenames, get) # dfs is a list of all the dataframes in the .GlobalEnv

for (i in index){
dfs = lapply(dfs, transform, Index = index[i])
}

list2env(dfs, envir = .GlobalEnv)
```

The loop runs, but doesn't change anything in `dfs`  and I don't get why.
For `list2env` I get the error message:

```
"Error in list2env(dfs, envir = .GlobalEnv) : 
  names(x) must be a character vector of the same length as x"
```

since there are `NA's` in the dataframes.

Is there a more direct way to change the dataframes in the .GlobalEnv directly and how does one iterate correctly trough a list of dataframes with a entry that changes for every dataframe (based on `index` list)?

I checked the questions regarding the Iteration in .GlobalEnv but non really seemed to make the entry dependend on iterating trough another list.

Thank you in advance :)

### Changes:

---

Sorry for my bad discription. I have a list of dataframes called `dfs`.
The list contains n=78 seperate dataframes. Then I have a second list `index` which contains n=78 "character" entries. 
My intention would be to take the first element of `dfs`, called `dataframe1` and add a column to it with the entry of the first element of `index` called `a`. For the second dataframe `dataframe2` in `dfs` I want to add a column with the second element of `index` called `b` and so on.

After doing that I would like to export the seperate dataframes of the updated `dfs`  to the .GlobalEnv. But since the seperate dataframes in `dfs` contain `NA's` that will not work with `list2env(dfs, .GlobalEnv)`.

Comment: Note that `c(a, b, c, d)` only makes sense if `a`, `b`, etc are variables with their own values.

Answer (score 0):

I am not fully understanding the question but here is what I believe is close to it.

First, create some data, since there is none in the question.

```
a <- 1
b <- 2
c <- 3
d <- 4
z <- 5

index <- c(a, b, c, d, z)

df1 <- iris
mt <- mtcars
diamonds <- as.data.frame(ggplot2::diamonds)
```

Now, change the dataframes above (note that there are only 3 df's) and assign back to the global environment.

```
objs <- ls()
lst <- mget(objs)
inx <- sapply(lst, class) == "data.frame"
objs <- objs[inx]
lst <- lst[inx]
lst <- lapply(seq_along(objs), function(i){
  DF <- lst[[i]]
  DF$Index <- index[[i]]
  DF
})
names(lst) <- objs
list2env(lst, envir = .GlobalEnv)
rm(lst)
```

Comment: @ Rui Barradas
I already have ```dfs``` and ```index``` and it therefore doesn't have to be generated :).
See my changes for better description of my problem. Thank you!

Comment: @ Rui Barradas```index``` is a list with element #1 = ```index[1] = a ```--> ```index= c(a, b, c, d, etc.). So ```index$a``` won't work.

Comment: @Mcgroger You also say that the dataframes in dfs contain NA's so `list2env` doesn't work. Can you be more specific? The dfs dataframes columns contain `NA`'s? And what doesn't work with `list2env`?